# Combine queries with different where clause conditions

Tags: sql

How do I combine these queries, so I can use `dayCall` from the second query in the first one?

**First query**

```
select clientid, 
DATEDIFF(
        DAY,
        CONVERT(datetime, convert(varchar(10), min(calendar))),
        MIN(dayCall)     
        )
from
Stats 
group by clientid
```

**Second query**

```
SELECT  
    clientid, 
    MIN(calendar)    
    as dayCall
FROM (
    SELECT 
        clientid, 
        CONVERT(datetime, convert(varchar(10), calendar)) calendar,
        lead(calls) over (partition by clientid order by calendar) as total_1,
        lead(calls, 2) over (partition by clientid order by calendar) as total_2
    FROM STATS

) a
where calls = 0 and total_1 = 0 and total_2 = 0
GROUP BY clientid
```

Comment: This might come off as apples to oranges to most of your readers.  It would be nice to include some sample data here, along with the expected output.

Comment: That second query is invalid. Should raise an error.

Comment: Use a CTE (Common Table Expression) to compute the second query, and then use it in the first one.

Answer (score 3):

You can join the tables together. I see clientID is common in both, but should do full outer join to make sure you get all results even if there is no common clientID between the two tables:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
select clientid, 
DATEDIFF(
        DAY,
        CONVERT(datetime, convert(varchar(10), min(calendar))),
        MIN(dayCall)     
        )
from
Stats 
group by clientid
) tableA
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(
SELECT  
    clientid, 
    MIN(calendar)    
    as dayCall
FROM (
    SELECT 
        clientid, 
        CONVERT(datetime, convert(varchar(10), calendar)) calendar,
        lead(calls) over (partition by clientid order by calendar) as total_1,
        lead(calls, 2) over (partition by clientid order by calendar) as total_2
    FROM STATS

) a
where calls = 0 and total_1 = 0 and total_2 = 0
GROUP BY clientid
) tableB
ON tableA.clientid = tableB.clientid
```

Comment: I get an `Invalid column name dayCall` error when its trying to do `MIN(dayCall)`

Comment: There may be something wrong with your original query. All I did was join the two queries together as requested. I did not test your original queries.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select clientid, 
       min(case when calls = 0 and total_1 = 0 and total_2 = 0 then calendar end) as dayCall,
       datediff(day
                convert(datetime, convert(varchar(10), min(calendar))),
                min(dayCall)     
               )
from (select s.*, 
             convert(datetime, convert(varchar(10), calendar)) calendar,
                     lead(calls) over (partition by clientid order by calendar) as total_1,
                     lead(calls, 2) over (partition by clientid order by calendar) as total_2
      from STATS s
     ) s
group by clientid
```

Comment: I get an `Invalid column name dayCall` error when its trying to do `MIN(dayCall)`

Comment: @Aaron . . . `DayCall` is in your first query.  I didn't invent it.  I edited the answer to take all columns from `STATS`.

Comment: Gordon, I think I wasn't clear earlier.  This line is throwing an error -`datediff(day
                convert(datetime, convert(varchar(10), min(calendar))),
                min(dayCall)     
               )`. It is not recognizing `dayCall` from the second line of the script.